# Triggering a callback only after all events occur

Tags: c#, events

I am trying to delay the execution of a method until all events to which it is subscribed have happened once. For example, some method might be the callback of two separate events:

```
classA.OnEvent += SomeMethod;
classB.OnEvent += SomeMethod;
```

I would like `SomeMethod()` to only trigger after both of these events have happened, or after `n` events happen in the general case. I am wondering if there is something in C# that can set this up for you. Right now I am just using something similar to the contrived code below:

```
using System;
                
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var publisherA = new Publisher();
        var publisherB = new Publisher();
        var subscriber = new Subscriber(publisherA, publisherB);
        publisherA.DoSomething();
        publisherB.DoSomething();
    }
}

public class Publisher 
{
    public event Action OnSomethingHappened;

    public void DoSomething() 
    {
        OnSomethingHappened.Invoke();
    }
}

public class Subscriber
{
    private bool a;
    private bool b;

    public Subscriber(Publisher publisherA, Publisher publisherB) 
    {
        publisherA.OnSomethingHappened += RecordPublisherA;
        publisherB.OnSomethingHappened += RecordPublisherB;
    }

    private void RecordPublisherA() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Recording publisherA");
        a = true;
        BothPublisherEventsTriggered();
    }

    private void RecordPublisherB() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Recording publisherB");
        b = true;
        BothPublisherEventsTriggered();
    }

    private void BothPublisherEventsTriggered() 
    {
        if (!a || !b)
            return;
    
        Console.WriteLine("Both publisher events triggered");
        a = b = false;
    }
}
```

Fiddle example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/5y4tW7

Comment: I think your solution is as good as it gets.

Comment: The [standard event pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/event-pattern) in .NET is for the publisher to identify itself as `sender` and doing an `Invoke(this)`.  That way you can have a single handler which can check which source triggered it.